# Does Apple allow me to reuse their icons in my own application?

Tags: objective-c, macos

In my **OS X application**, I allow the user to open a Finder window. I would like to use the Finder's icon on my "open Finder" button. My application will be going to the App Store, but I would rather preempt any violation of Apple's policy on using their icons.

So, would such reuse be allowed by Apple? And, could anybody provide a corresponding reference to Apple's documentation? (I thought I had read it was not allowed, but I cannot find it now.)

UPDATE:
To handle cases were the application of interest is not running, I used superfell's answer of a previous question, [12166532](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166532/get-icon-for-another-application-in-objective-c?rq=1), as follows:

```
// Return an application's icon using its bundle identifier
- (NSImage *) applicationIconWithBundleIdentifier: (NSString *) bundleIdentifier
{
    NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:NSImageNameComputer]; // fallback icon

    NSString *path = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
    if (path) {
        image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:path];
    }

    return image;
}
```

But, I am very grateful to Rob's answers below for putting me on the right track.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get icon for another application in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12166532/get-icon-for-another-application-in-objective-c)

Comment: Why is my question off topic? Is it not concerning "practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession" as defined in the FAQ?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/ might be a better forum for asking this sort of question, because this can't be answered with a programming answer as much as it can be answered by experts who know what Apple will allow.

Comment: John, thank you for providing an answer. Although, apple.stackexchange seems more focused on end-users to me, and my question is coding relevant. Anyway, jogging-on, thanks again.

Comment: well, as you stated in your UPDATE (which refers to the "possible duplicate" i indicated in the 1st comment), the answer does have a duplicate answer elsewhere, and that's another valid reason to vote to close SO issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably fine, in the sense that Apple's unlikely to go after you for such use.  It's also probably fine, in the sense that applications provide icons specifically for other programs (like the Finder) to display for the purposes of manipulating the apps.  Whether you get sued is really up to Apple's legal department, and whether you would win is up to your country's copyright law (and fair use exceptions to that law).  You can ask Apple for explicit permission; details are on [their web site](http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/rightsandpermissions.html).

Anyway, if you fail the App Store review, change the icon.  No big deal.

You probably don't want to hard-code the icon.  Instead, get the icon at runtime like this:

```
NSImage *imageForAppWithBundleIdentifier(NSString *bundleIdentifier) {
    NSWorkspace *workspace = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
    NSString *appPath = [workspace absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier:bundleIdentifier];
    return [workspace iconForFile:appPath];
}
```

Finder's bundle identifier is `com.apple.finder`.  Terminal's bundle identifier is `com.apple.Terminal`.

```
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Finder" to get id'
com.apple.finder
$ osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to get id'
com.apple.Terminal
```

Comment: Hi Rob, nice idea. 
The problem is the technique fails for querying another application (e.g. Terminal) that might not be already running.
I have been bitten by using Finder in my example.

Comment: So, any suggestions for getting the icon of a non-running application from its bundle identifier?

Comment: There's a trivial typo in the code: `return [workspace iconForFile:bundleIdentifier];` should obviously be `return [workspace iconForFile:appPath];`.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.apple.com/legal/intellectual-property/guidelinesfor3rdparties.html

> Apple Logo and Apple-owned Graphic Symbols: **You may not use the Apple Logo or any other Apple-owned graphic symbol, logo, or icon** on or in connection with web sites, products, packaging, manuals, promotional/advertising materials, or for any other purpose except pursuant to an express written trademark license from Apple, such as a reseller agreement.

This basically applies for any company. If you don't have explicit license to use graphics, don't use them.

Comment: Hmm.  I didn't grant Apple an explicit license to my app's icon.  Yet they are showing it in their own app (the Finder).  Shall I sue them?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I don't know about the Finder icon.  We used something similar to the icon above on a toolbar menu.  They rejected a software update by saying the following.

*5.1*

*The app uses the Home icon in the main application window in a manner that is not consistent with Apple's trademark guidelines.*

That was late-September, 2011, according to our records.

Comment: I'd guess the rejection was because you used a familiar icon for an unfamiliar task. That icon would probably be fine if it linked to the user's home directory.

Answer (score 1):

This might not help very much, but considering they have [licensing and trademark](https://developer.apple.com/softwarelicensing/) documents, I would assume that if you could use what you want to market your product, there should be no issue with placing it within your application. I'll see if I can find a more definitive document.

Also found this from a [Cocoabuilder forum](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/292033-using-apple-icons.html).